# Providing graphics with own package

Tags: graphics, package-writing

Is it possible to provide graphics with own packages?

I have modified a beamer style and added a graphic to each page by using `\includegraphics`:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{
  \begin{textblock*}{200mm}(.84\textwidth,-8mm)
    \includegraphics[height=7mm]{myGraphic}
  \end{textblock*}
}
```

I want to make use of this style in diferent presentations. So, I decided to create a package (`.sty`) out of it. This is working fine but the graphic is only found if placed in the folder of the presentation. I would realy like to place the graphic with the package. Is it possible? And if it is, how?

Comment: In most setups the TeX input path is searched for images so if tex is finding your .sty file it should be finding the image. But it depends on the drivers and image inclusions being used at the back end. So you need to say exactly what tex engine you are using, and what error you get if it doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of the [`mwe` Package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe). The (main) purpose of this package is to provide example graphics for minimal working examples, so it can serve as a minimal basis for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You can use both relative and absolute addresses with things like \includegraphics{}.  "foo.jpg" is in the local folder, "../graphics/foo.jpb" is in another folder next to this folder, and "H:/foo.jpg" is on a flash drive (H:).

Comment: @David Carlisle you are right, the problem was just, that I didn't realy "installed" the .sty file but used it with \usepackage{somefolder/myPackage}. Maybe you can make your comment an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most setups the TeX input path is searched for images so if tex is finding your .sty file it should be finding the image. But it depends on the drivers and image inclusions being used at the back end.

Note that it is wrong to use a filepath with `\usepackage` although it sometimes works it will generate a warning if `ProvidesPackage` is used, and it makes the documents unportable.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying a very similar thing and at first my graphics file wasn't found either.

Then I realised I simply had to refresh the name database of my LaTeX distribution. After doing so, the system would find the graphic file (that I placed together with my package into my local texmf tree) just fine. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7.